# Rails. For different pages of different script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

It was first added to the carousel in the project. She displayed correctly. Аfter adding cards to another page carousel broke down. How to make a script acted for one page, and for each other?

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery.validate
//= require validation
//= require jquery-1.5.min
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require markerclusterer
//= require google_maps
//= require jcarousel
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialise the first and second carousel by class selector.
    // Note that they use both the same configuration options (none in this case).
    $('.d-carousel .carousel').jcarousel({
        scroll: 1
    });

});
```

**google_maps.js:**

```
$(function() {
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({provider: {scrollwheel: false}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function () {
        var ht = 80;
        var wt = 80;
        markers = handler.addMarkers([
            {
                "lat": 23.953052,
                "lng": 56.677616,
                "picture": {
                    "url": src="../../assets/kafe.png",
                    "width": wt,
                    "height": ht
                },
                "infowindow": "kafe"
            }
        ]);
        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
});
```

**jcarousel.js:**

```
(function ($) {
        $.jcarousel = function (e, o) { ... })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try remove the

```
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require markerclusterer
```

line from application.js and add to google_maps.js.
Add line in view `<%= javascript_include_tag "google_maps.js", params[:you_controller] %>`.
In *config/initializers/assets.rb* add

```
    %w( controller_one controller_two controller_three ).each do |controller|
      Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["#{controller}.js.coffee", "#{controller}.css"]
    end
    Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( google_maps.js )
```

and restart server
and check worked jquery.turbolinks